# Qmake: how to remove compiler flag for a certain project, without changing qmake.conf?

Tags: c++, qt, qmake, compiler-options

I'm using `qmake` and Visual Studio. In release build qmake adds /GL and /O2 flags to all projects, and I need to remove those two flags for certain libraries within my whole Qt project. Is there a way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way this could work is

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS -= /GL /O2
```

but I doubt this works for `QMAKE_CFLAGS`.

Alternatively, you could redefine `QMAKE_CFLAGS`, forgetting its previous value:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS = $$CFLAGS_WITHOUT_GL_O2
```

Comment: tried `-=` - no luck. And the second solution is so obvious I didn't even think about it :)

Answer (score 10):

I had a similar problem and I solved it by adding the following directive in the .pro file:

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -g

Observe the _RELEASE suffix, otherwise don't work.

Answer (score 5):

I edited my .pro file by using this, and it worked!

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE  -= -Zc:strictStrings
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -Zc:strictStrings
```

It does not work:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -Zc:strictStrings
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -Zc:strictStrings
```

You can try:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE  -= -GL -O2
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE_WITH_DEBUGINFO -= -GL -O2
```

Take a look in:

your Qt dir\compiler\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013\qmake.conf

Comment: I believe checking the .conf file can't be underscored enough

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the qmakespec which is used by your configuration.

The easiest way to find it is by opening

```
%QTDIR%\mkspecs\%QMAKESPEC%
```

assuming the environment variables are set (they should be)

Just in case it's not working, it will be something like `C:\Qt\4.x.x\mkspecs\win32-msvc2010`

In the qmake.conf file you can adjust the folling two lines (they are in different places in the file)

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -O2 -MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       = -GL
```

to

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    = -MT
QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       =
```

However note that you will have to do this for every Qt Version you are using (and for every future update you will do).

[Edit]
If you want to have -O2 -GL options for certain projects you will have to add

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE    += -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS_LTCG       += -GL
```

to the .pro file of the projects which need those options.

Dependent on the amount of projects which use it and the ones which don't, either this approach or redefining QMAKE_CFLAGS will be more convenient.

Answer (score 1):

If `-=` does not work

try in your .pro file

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS = $$replace(QMAKE_CFLAGS, "-GL ", "")
QMAKE_CFLAGS = $$replace(QMAKE_CFLAGS, "-O2 ", "")
```

Answer (score 1):

With Qt 5.15.2 on MacOSX (Xcode 13) none of the other answers worked for me in a QtCreator project.

The default setting with `CONFIG += warn_on` has `-Wall -Wextra`.

What I wanted to add was:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter
```

but adding this causes the additional compiler flags to be added to the compilation command before `-Wall -Wextra` and it doesn't work.

Turns out that those flags are added by the `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON` variable in
`/path/to/Qt/5.15.2/clang_64/mkspecs/common/gcc-base.conf`.

So to temporarily add them after the `-Wall -Wextra` flags I did this:

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-parameter

Now I have all the other warnings but not the `unused-*` ones.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced the same problem. I had to remove the Zc:strictStrings compiler flag. I've learned immediately that just removing does not work. So, the solution is to override the flag by including this string into .pro file

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-Zc:strictStrings-`

Like this the compiler prints a warning: cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/Zc:strictStrings' with '/Zc:strictStrings-' but still it does the job.

Answer (score -1):

What worked for me was adding the following in the .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -Zc:strictStrings
```

Comment: Please add details explaining what the line of code does. I suggest details on where this line is used (in a config file or from the command line), and an explanation of how this line removes the flags from the whole project. This will help others learn and evaluate whether the provided answer applies to them.