# qmake configuration

Tags: qt, qmake

How I change qmake configuration. In all projects which I make, qmake puts `-fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -DQT_NO_DYNAMIC_CAST` flags in Makefile.Realease and other undesirable flags. How I can change this behavior.

I am on Windows. I use mingw-64 (ruben build). I used the following commands to build qt 4.8.3:

```
    ..\src\configure.exe -opensource -confirm-license -plugin-sql-mysql -plugin-sql-sqlite -no-dsp -no-vcproj -no-qt3support -no-phonon -no-phonon-backend -platform win32-g++  -largefile -fontconfig -no-webkit -nomake examples -nomake demos -prefix "D:\qt\4.8.3\x86_64-w64-mingw32"  -I "D:\mysql\include" -L "D:\mysql\lib" -l mysql

make

make install
```

Comment: This question is very similar to [Qmake: how to remove compiler flags...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241567/qmake-how-to-remove-compiler-flag-for-a-certain-project-without-changing-qmake).  Perhaps you answer is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it help when you add `exceptions` and `rtti` to your `CONFIG` variable?

```
CONFIG += exceptions rtti
```

You should probably make sure that your custom Qt build has exception and rtti support enabled:

```
configure.exe -exceptions -rtti [...]
```