# Makefile generation: How to prevent QMake from setting compile flags

Tags: qt, qmake

I am overriding some QMAKE variables with my own values. However, when I check the makefile QMake generated, I can see that QMake is putting some extra values in it and I can't find a way to prevent that, or to "clean" a variable.

Here is a sample of my project file :

```
marvell_release {
    QMAKE_CC=/usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-gcc
    QMAKE_CXX=/usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-g++
    QMAKE_CFLAGS=-pipe
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS=-pipe
    QMAKE_LINK=/usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-ld
    QMAKE_LFLAGS=
}
```

And here is what QMake generated from the project file :

```
CC            = /usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-gcc
CXX           = /usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-g++
DEFINES       = 
CFLAGS        = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE $(DEFINES)
CXXFLAGS      = -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -fPIE $(DEFINES)
INCPATH       = -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/mkspecs/linux-g++-64
LINK          = /usr/local/arm-marvell-linux-gnu/bin/arm-marvell-linux-gnu-ld
LFLAGS        = -Wl,-O1
```

As you can see, the LFLAGS variable contains two options that I didn't specify and that I would like to remove. Does anyone know how to do that, or the explanation of why are these values being appended?

Comment: Have you tried using `-=` as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15482574/1062948) example? Not sure if it will work but is worth a try. For example, `QMAKE_LFLAGS -= -W1,-O1` or `QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE -= -W1,-O1`.

Comment: Those are useful defaults: -O2 for release builds, -O0 für debug; Some basic warnings and so on. qmake is made to set those values even if your .pro file is as minimal as possible. So the question is, which value exactly is the issue and how to override it.

Comment: @crazeewulf, 
Yes I tried the -= and it didn't work. I just tried the QMAKE_LFLAGS_RELEASE now and it didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

Custom your own mkspec for qmake, reference could be: https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/tree/5.5/mkspecs/devices

Comment: That's a possible solution for my problem, but this solution has its drawbacks : whever Qt gets updated I will need to reinstall my mkspec for the new version.
I am really after a project-based solution.