# How to disable optimization of mingw in Qt

Tags: gcc, mingw, qmake

I am trying to close the optimization of C code in release mode like:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -O2
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -O0
```

But

```
gcc -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -O0 -O2 -Wall -W -Wextra -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -I../cqmake -I. -IC:/Qt/Qt5.10.1/5.10.1/mingw53_32/mkspecs/win32-g++  -o release/main.o ../cqmake/main.c
g++ -Wl,-s -Wl,-subsystem,console -mthreads -o release/cqmake.exe release/main.o
```

`-O2` did not removed.

Answer (score 0):

[qmake-how-to-remove-compiler-flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241567/qmake-how-to-remove-compiler-flag-for-a-certain-project-without-changing-qmake) will give you some hint.

One reason maybe that when executing `QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -O2`, -O2 has not been added to compiler flag list.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, `QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -O2` did work, the suffix is necessary.