# unrecognized command-line option "-mfloat-abi=softfp" | Qt Cross Compilation for Raspberry Pi 4 | Debian 11 aarch64

Tags: qt, raspberry-pi, debian, cross-compiling, arm64

I've installed Debian Bullseye from this page:
https://raspi.debian.net/daily-images/

on a Raspberry Pi 4 machine and prepared the required libraries and packages following these guides:

https://www.interelectronix.com/qt-515-cross-compilation-raspberry-compute-module-4-ubuntu-20-lts.html

https://github.com/abhiTronix/raspberry-pi-cross-compilers/blob/master/QT_build_instructions.md

This is the compiler I'm using: https://snapshots.linaro.org/gnu-toolchain/12.0-2021.10-1/aarch64-linux-gnu/gcc-linaro-12.0.0-2021.10-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu.tar.xz

from this page: https://snapshots.linaro.org/gnu-toolchain/12.0-2021.10-1/aarch64-linux-gnu/

---

**issue description**

When I run ./configure... after some processing the compiler throws an error:

> aarch64-linux-gnu-g++: error: unrecognized command-line option `-mfloat-abi=softfp`

Meanwhile, Linaro or official ARM compilers do not support VFP, FPU, etc. so I had to change the qmake.conf to try to remove that command-line option from the compiler flags.

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS -= -mfloat-abi=softfp
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE -= -mfloat-abi=softfp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS -= -mfloat-abi=softfp
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE -= -mfloat-abi=softfp
```

I've tried every solution listed on: [Qmake: how to remove compiler flag for a certain project, without changing qmake.conf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8241567/qmake-how-to-remove-compiler-flag-for-a-certain-project-without-changing-qmake)

But still had no luck! That command-line magically appears again!

Have you had any luck compiling for aarch64?

How can I resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

my configure command:

```
~/Qt/5.15.2/Src/configure -release -device linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ \
-device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/tools/gcc-linaro-12.0.0-2021.10-x86_64_aarch64-linux-gnu/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu- \
-sysroot ~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/sysroot -prefix /usr/local/qt5.15.2 \
-extprefix ~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/qt5.15.2 \
-opensource -confirm-license -skip qtscript -skip qtwayland -skip qtwebengine \
-nomake tests -make libs -pkg-config -no-use-gold-linker -v -recheck \
-L~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu \
-I~/Documents/Qt-CrossCompile-RaspberryPi/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu
```

I edited qmake.conf in linux-rasp-pi4-v3d-g++ folder:

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)

#QMAKE_LIBS_EGL         += -lEGL
#QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL_ES2  += -lGLESv2 -lEGL

#QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72 -mfpu=crypto-neon-fp-armv8
QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

#DISTRO_OPTS            += hard-float
DISTRO_OPTS            += deb-multi-arch

#EGLFS_DEVICE_INTEGRATION = eglfs_kms

include(../common/linux_arm_device_post.conf)

QMAKE_CFLAGS            = $$replace(QMAKE_CFLAGS, "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "")
QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE            = $$replace(QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE, "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "")
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$replace(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS, "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "")
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE          = $$replace(QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_RELEASE, "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "")

COMPILER_FLAGS            = $$replace(COMPILER_FLAGS, "-mfloat-abi=softfp", "")

load(qt_config)
```

Comment: The instructions are assuming you are building for 32-bit ARM, whereas it sounds like you have installed a 64-bit operating system and are running your device in 64-bit mode.  The `-mfloat-abi=softfp` is applicable to ARM32 only.  You can see the string `arm` throughout those instructions, e.g. `arm-linux-gnueabihf`, and that means 32-bit ARM.  You would want to see `arm64` or `aarch64` there instead.

Comment: So you either need to figure out how to adapt those instructions to aarch64, or find better instructions, or reinstall your Raspberry Pi with a 32-bit OS.  (Most tutorials on "how to do X on a Raspberry Pi" assume you are running it in 32-bit mode, because that's what Raspbian does, and so it's the more popular choice for most RPi users.)

Comment: @NateEldredge I updated the question with my configure command, and the modified qmake.conf - would you please take a look?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any specific knowledge about the Qt build process, so I can't help with how to do it correctly.  Perhaps you would have better luck on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

fixed this by editing the qmake.conf

used `linux_device_post` instead of `linux_arm_device_post`

```
include(../common/linux_device_pre.conf)
QT_QPA_DEFAULT_PLATFORM =

QMAKE_CFLAGS            = -march=armv8-a -mtune=cortex-a72
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS          = $$QMAKE_CFLAGS

DISTRO_OPTS            += deb-multi-arch

include(../common/linux_device_post.conf)

load(qt_config)
```